# Remove all empty strings from an array in Zsh

Tags: zsh, array

How do I remove all empty strings from a Zsh array?

```
a=('a' '' 'b' 'c')
# remove empty elements from array
echo ${(j./.)a}
```

Should output `a/b/c`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is the parameter expansion `${name:#pattern}` (pattern can be empty), which will work on elements of an array:

```
a=('a' '' 'b' 'c')
echo ${(j./.)a:#}
# If the expansion is in double quotes, add the @ flag:
echo "${(@j./.)a:#}"
```

---

`man 1 zshexpn`:

> `${name:#pattern}` If the pattern matches the value of name, then substitute the empty string; otherwise, just substitute the value of name.  If name is an array the matching array elements are removed (use the `(M)` flag to remove the non-matched elements).

Comment: +1 the non-klunky way ;)

Answer (score 10):

That's what `zsh` does by default when you leave a parameter expansion unquoted¹.

So:

```
a=($a)
```

Will remove the empty elements in the `$a` array.

---

<sup>¹ [I generally consider that a misfeature](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2009/msg00630.html). See the `rc`/`es` or `fish` shells for better arrays that don't do that. That's probably there so as to provide some level of compatibility with the sparse arrays of `ksh`/`bash`. `ksh`/`bash` arrays not only do empty removal upon unquoted array expansion (written `${a[@]}` there), but also split+glob, which means you can't really use arrays unquoted there unless you disable globbing and set `$IFS` to the empty string  (`IFS=; set -o noglob; a=(${a[@]})` then does empty removal only there like in `zsh` in addition to making the array non-sparse)</sup>

Comment: Re ¹: Shame, as that basically means you still have to quote many array expansions just in case, particularly when passing along arguments. I take it there's no option to disable that misfeature?

Comment: @ak2, not that many as most of the time, at least in my experience, arrays are used for lists of files or in general things other than the empty string. Note that you need `"$array[@]"` or `"${(@)array}"`, to expand to all the elements including empty ones. `"$array"` is like `"$array[*]"` which is the elements joined with the first character of `$IFS`.

Comment: Thank you. Luckily, for script/function arguments, there's the still quite concise `"$@"`.

Answer (score 8):

Well, zsh has a `:|` parameter expansion operator for *array* subtraction - so a klunky way to do it would be to define a second array consisting of only an empty element

```
b=('')
```

and then do

```
 % echo ${(j./.)a:|b}

a/b/c
```

However it feels like there *ought* to be a way to do it without the additional array

... and indeed [there is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590047/65304).